# How to enable object for rendering

Tags: rendering

When I try to bake a normal map I get the message "object xxx is not enabled for rendering".

I found some topics but the hotkeys (Space) for  doesn't work. In fact with Space I get a lot of functions but nowhere a hint how to clear the restrictions.

In SceneCollection the capera is on (same effect if off), the object is visible.

Any idea how to toggle the render permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, seems I was stuck in a stupid way.
I selected in the SceneCollection the objects BUT NOT the group. So far the the object itself shows the camera but slightly grayed out.
[image: The way to enable rendering]

You have to enable the full object path to enable rendering eventually.